# How to reshape muliple data frames

Tags: r, for-loop, dataframe, reshape, lapply

I have data frame called data

```
head (data)

        Date Station variable  value
1 2004-06-10  Tushka       US 173.62
2 2004-06-11  Tushka       US 173.57
3 2004-06-12  Tushka       US 173.52
4 2004-06-13  Tushka       US 173.47
5 2004-06-14  Tushka       US 173.43
6 2004-06-15  Tushka       US 173.39

levels(as.factor(data$Station))

[1] "AbuSimbel" "AdinE"     "AdinW"     "Afia"      "ARQE"      "ARQW"      "Garf"      "Tushka"

levels(data$variable)

 [1] "US"  "PW1" "PW2" "PW3" "PW4" "W1"  "W4"  "PW7" "PW8" "PE1" "PE3" "PE4" "E1"  "PE2"
```

I used the code:

```
list_df <- split(data, data$Station)
```

I got a list of 8 data frames ("AbuSimbel", "AdinE", "AdinW","Afia","ARQE","ARQW", "Garf","Tushka")

to reshape the 8 data frames from long to wide I had to repeat the code 8 times for each station

```
Tushka <- reshape(Tushka, timevar = "variable",idvar = c("Date","Station"),direction = "wide")
```

my question is how I can use the reshape code for the list_df without repeating the code 8 times using for-loop function

Comment: Please use `dput()` with your data frame to allow reproducibility. Showing your desired output would also improve your question. I think that you should create another question/post about cross-correlation.

Comment: `lapply(list_df, tidyr::spread, key = variable, value = value)` ought to do it for question 1. I'd suggest you ask question 2 separately. You could probably `lapply(list_df, reshape, timevar = "variable", idvar = c("Date", "Station"), direction = "wide")` if you want to stay in `base`.

Comment: Given that it sounds like all of the data.frames are in the same format and already identified as different with a variable, I'd just combine them into one with `do.call(rbind, list_df)` or the dplyr or data.table equivalents, so the reshaping and manipulation is simpler.

Comment: @alistaire They started all in one (OP shows the `split` code). This was my first reaction as well, but if the `Station` values have different `variable`  values nested within each of them, going *so* wide might not be desirable.

Comment: Could someone use for-loop for the first question?